# spy with LibCEC on Raspberry pi

Tags: c++, c, hdmi

I'm trying to use LibCEC for listen HDMI-CEC devices on my local network.

I want to obtain all CEC information from all devices.
Actually LibCEC give me information about broadcasting and direct messages to my raspberry pi, but not about direct messages between other devices (for example between my TV and my ps4).

I want to undo this limitation, to be able to spy every messages on the network.

I looked for the filter in LibCEC, but i didn't find where it was filtered.

Does someone tried to create a CEC listener or has any idea of where is locate this filter?

Comment: Huh? Isn't [HDMI-CEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consumer_Electronics_Control) traffic going through HDMI cables? I don't see how a Raspberry Pi can see the traffic between two unrelated devices? Or is the RaspPi connected to the same TV as the PS4?

Comment: Yes, i have my tv, the RaspPi on HDMI 1 and PS4 on HDMI 2.
When I wake up the PS4, it's wake up the TV, but I can't see the CEC commands with the LibCEC for raspberry

Comment: But, uh, doesn't the term "direct messages between other devices" imply that the message is not physically present on the link to the Pi? I would assume that the TV acts as a switch, not as a hub?

Comment: The TV acts like a hub. I have a tool which print all cec messages at work, and when I use it on HDMI 1, I can see every messages between TV and HDMI 2.
But I haven't this at home, and I would like to use my pi like that, but with LibCEC I haven't everything.
So to me there is a filter somewhere in the LibCEC but I can't find where

Comment: The CEC line is a shared bus between all connected HDMI devices. Its wiring is mandatory even in non-CEC enabled devices, so it should be easy to snoop on every message output to the CEC line. Please update your question with an answer, if you've found a solution, as I have the same problem.